# No such file or directory in Arduino Project

Tags: c++, arduino, publish-subscribe

I'm very new in `Arduino`, so maybe my question will be stupid but I have to ask it!

I made a `mqtt` client for my `nodeMcu` chip, and I have this error

> /Users/mikevorisis/Downloads/pubsubclient-master/examples/mqtt_esp8266/mqtt_esp8266.ino:27:26:
>   fatal error: PubSubClient.h: No such file or directory  #include

I downloaded the original [project](https://github.com/knolleary/pubsubclient/tree/v2.6) from github and I tried to compile the example it has in examples/mqtt_esp8266 but again I have the same problem.

I also tried to put the PubSubClient.h in the same folder but again I have the same problem.

Any ideas? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The file you have downloaded and included in your project is probably not actually a header file. You probably copied the contents of it from github and pasted it into a text document which you saved as a text file with the extension ".h".

It now has the extension "filename.h.txt". The name and extension need to be only "filename.h". Use save as, and select "all files" when saving, and name it "filename.h". Be sure to retype the filename, or it can be auto-filled with the already existing "filename.h.txt" (even if you don's see it!).

If the file now has the right extension, put it in the same folder as your source code file. You can see which directory your source file is in by going to "save as" in your IDE.

---

A problem you might run into after this is missing definitions. You see, when you use libraries in the form of header files, each header file must *usually* (in this case, yes) be accompanied by a .cpp file (not necessarily with the same name). The reason for this is that the header file contains declarations, and the cpp file the definitions for said declarations. In other words, the header file is an overview of the facilities available in the library, and the cpp file actually implements the guts of it.

---

Edit: The example you are trying to run also has `#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>`, a file that is not available in the github repository that you referred to. I assume that this is a library for a WiFi module or such that you can get elsewhere (manufacturer, other git's or maybe it comes with the Arduino IDE?). In other words, you also need to add its header and (probably) .cpp file to your source directory.

Comment: Hi Tellus thanks for your answer, I checked the extension and its .h (I also renamed as you said) but nothing changed. I also put them in the same folder. I actually try to run the example from the repo in github so if you have the time to check it you'd see the error.

Comment: Did you also get the .cpp file for the header and do you have it in the same directory as the header file and the source?

Comment: yes I have them in the same folder.. I will check if i put them in the same folder as espwifi will do the trick

Comment: One more thing. Are you writing #include <filename.h> or #include "filename.h"?

Comment: I use this `#include <filename.h>`

Comment: Right. Change it to use quotation marks, but not for the WiFi-header.

Comment: Searching for the libraries I found out that if I go to sketch -> include library ->manage libraries I could download PubSubClient and the error has gone but now I have for the wifi the same error and I installed 4 libraries none of them is working I might have to search to put it manually.

Comment: The ESP8266WiFi library is part of the ESP8266 core for Arduino. This is a complete hardware package to add support for directly programming the ESP8266 to the Arduino IDE. In this case you need to install the complete hardware package. Just the library alone won't do you any good. Please follow these instructions exactly: https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino#installing-with-boards-manager